# Change default controller directory of Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to have two folders where save codeigniter's controllers:

```
/application/controllers
/application/buckets
```

i'm a order paranoic person and i want to separate two types of my controllers.

In bucket folders the structure app was this:

```
/application/buckets/example/index.php
/application/buckets/example2/index.php
/application/buckets/example3/index.php
```

¿Maybe extending the router class?

A working example:

```
<?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

/*
    Extended the core Router class to allow for sub-sub-folders in the controllers directory.
*/
class App_Router extends CI_Router {

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function _validate_request($segments)
    {
        if (count($segments) == 0)
        {
            return $segments;
        }

        if (file_exists(APPPATH.'buckets/'.$segments[0].'/index.php'))
        {


            $this->set_directory(APPPATH.'buckets/'.$segments[0]);
            $this->set_class(ucfirst($segments[0]));
            $this->set_method(isset($segments[1]) ? $segments[1] : 'index');

            return $segments;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You could have subfolders inside _controllers_. [Organizing Your Controllers into Sub-directories](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/controllers.html#organizing-your-controllers-into-sub-directories)

Comment: The downside I see is, if you care about the url showing the subfolder, I think you'd have to route every method for each controller.

Comment: i found this: http://developers.ph/codeigniter/hmvc-pattern-codeigniter-php-framework/

Comment: If you're really paranoid about the location of your controllers, then what does changing their location do? It does nothing. If somebody has access to your filesystem, they're going to find your controllers no matter where they are. You should probably be thinking about server security, as that's where your protection will come from.

Comment: Possible [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Hierarchical MVC(HMVC) with Codeigniter to accomplish this.

For reference, see [Modular Extensions - HMVC](https://bitbucket.org/wiredesignz/codeigniter-modular-extensions-hmvc)

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look into parent-child controller ...one extending another. To be more clear you can make as many controller you want.

I Agreed with @Brian Gottier : "what does changing their location do?"
You can perform anything if you have core functionalities in your hands.
You can play around with hooks (**CodeIgniter's Hooks feature provides a means to tap into and modify the inner workings of the framework without hacking the core files. When CodeIgniter runs it follows a specific execution process, diagramed in the Application Flow page.**)

Create "Base"/"Admin"/"Public"/"XYZ" Controllers in

application/core/MY_Controller.php

and keep rest of your controllers in same application/controller folder

MY_Controller is a basic core library extension. Whenever you create a class with the MY_ prefix the CodeIgniter Loader class will load this after loading the core library.

All we have done here is create a base class that all of our Controllers and "controller types" will inherit. Anything we put in here and assign to $this will be available to anything that extends this class.

Base Controllers are a nice simple way to give you global data, logic and shared code which can be specific to a certain part of your site. They can do all sorts of crazy stuff which I will leave for you to think about.

I Hope this help.